# Linux won't respect routing table

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing

I created a VPN connection.

Here's my routing table after I connect:

```
lz@jetson:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.255.5   0.0.0.0         UG    50     0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
191.37.145.144  192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.255.1   192.168.255.5   255.255.255.255 UGH   50     0        0 tun0
192.168.255.5   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    50     0        0 tun0
```

As you see, `192.168.0.x` should go through `tun0`, but it goes through `eth0`, `192.168.0.1` end in my router.

```
ip route get 192.168.0.1
192.168.0.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.0.12 uid 1000 
    cache
```

I tried giving metric `0` for `tun0` but it won't do anything

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.255.5
```

did the trick but it's too much. Why linux wont respect the routing table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overlooking these entries:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth0
```

Both of them also match your destination, and both have a longer prefix length than your "tun0" route (i.e. they have more '1' bits in the mask) – the first one is /24 and therefore is always higher priority than the 0.0.0.0/0 "tun" route, while the second is /32 and has highest priority out of all.

As a general rule, routing table entries are chosen by "longest prefix match"; that is, the primary priority value is the prefix length. Route metric is *only* used as a secondary "tie-breaker" value, to choose between multiple routes when they have equal prefix lengths.

Comment: That's odd, I've never had to configure local routes my hand in Open VPN, they've always gone by default.

Comment: Maybe you used a smart VPN client that configured _policy routing_ (`ip rule`)? That would allow the VPN to override a whole routing table, e.g. based on fwmark or TCP/UDP port.